# Socketio wont run, getting io.connection not a function

Tags: socket.io

Using this code on the client side:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
});
</script>
```

Getting this error:

"io.connect is not a function"

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Firefox. Actually I think I got it to work, however the problem is when I look in firebug I get an error message http://127.0.0.1:8888/socket.io/xhr-multipart/ aborted. And it does this over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was I had to use my external ip address for the server this script is running on.

Comment: yes, you are right. I found your answer to be working correctly. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that `http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js` is code for Socket.IO 0.6 and you are using the Socket.IO 0.7+ API.

The CDN has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Here is a wiki about how to serve the socket.io client in your HTML pages: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client